# Azure flask app deployed always shows the default landing page

Tags: azure, flask, web-applications, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have deployed a simple Flask application on an azure webapp by forking the repo from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/python-docs-hello-world

Here is my application.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"


@app.route("/sms")
def hello_sms():
    return "Hello World SMS!"


# if __name__ == '__main__':
#    app.run(debug = True)
```

And this is my requirements.txt

```
click==6.7
Flask==1.0.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

At first when I opened the URL ( https://staysafe.azurewebsites.net/ ) i got this message, "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
After which i when to the application settings in the webapp dashboard in azure and set a python version.
And ever since this is what I get when i open my URL 
[image: open url]

Any clue as to what is going wrong?

Comment: have you created an virtual environment?

Comment: No. is it required to run in on the webapp?

Comment: no, it not required. But I recommend to use it for ignoring something missing. You can follow this official [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python), I used your code, and works fine.

Comment: I had the same problem where logs are saying everything is correct but still getting the default page. The problem is the ending "/" in url. My firefox was removing the ending "/" in the url but it works fine with internet explorer.
https://xyz.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seams that your code is not uploaded to portal.

Please follow this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python) for your test.

I Used your code from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/python-docs-hello-world, and works fine. The steps as below:

Environment: python3.7, windows 10

1.Open git bash,download the code to local using `git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/python-docs-hello-world.git`

2.In git bash, execute `cd python-docs-hello-world`

3.In git bash, execute following command one by one:

```
py -3 -m venv venv
venv/scripts/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
FLASK_APP=application.py flask run
```

4.Open a web browser, and navigate to the sample app at http://localhost:5000/ .

It is to make sure it can work well in local.

5.Then just follow the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python) to create deployment credetial / resource group / service plan / a web app

6.If no issues, in git bash, push the code to azure:

```
git remote add azure <deploymentLocalGitUrl-from-create-step>
```

Then execute `git push azure master`

7.Browse to the website like https://your_app_name.azurewebsites.net, or https://your_app_name.azurewebsites.net/sms,

it works fine, screenshot as below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I was following an outdated guide on youtube